# Best way to verify that passenger nginx module has been successfully compiled?

Tags: nginx, chef-infra, passenger

I have several servers chef managed each running a stack with:

- nginx
- phusion passenger

I'd like to make the passenger gem upgrade process automated with the ability to conditionally skip passenger nginx module compilation meaning I don't want the compile process to happen on every chef run, only on runs where it is determined that it is necessary (typically because passenger gem version is being upgraded, but also in cases where the passenger gem is not being upgraded but the compilation failed previously).

Currently I check the version of passenger being run, but in cases where the gem actually installs to the correct version but the compilation fails, that idempotency check is too broad and I fail to get a compile attempt when I need one.

What is the most accurate way to verify that the passenger nginx module has been compiled? Is there a specific file in a stable location whose existence I can check for?

Right now my chef block looks like this:

```
execute "compile passenger nginx module" do
    ruby_vers = node[:ruby][:global_version]
    passenger_vers = node[:passenger][:version]
    ruby_parent_vers = node[:ruby_parent_vers]
  command "export ORIG_PATH=\"$PATH\"; sudo -s -E; export PATH=\"$ORIG_PATH\"; /usr/bin/ruby /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/passenger-#{passenger_vers}/bin/passenger-install-nginx-module --auto --auto-download"
  # check for a difference between passenger version requested and passenger version running
  not_if { `passenger --version` == cur_vers }
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `passenger-config about compiled`?

Comment: No I had not. Did not know it existed! Thanks for sharing. However, when I try `passenger-config about compiled` or `passenger-config about nginx-dynamic-compiled `, both return nothing.

Comment: They only "return" an exit code. 0 for ok/yes non-0 for bad/no.

Comment: Ah, okay, I see, yes, I'm getting exit code 0. Just need to test if I get a proper exit code for when it is fact not compiled. Thanks!

Comment: Recently was able to verify this works as expected. `passenger-config about compiled` returns exit code of 1 when the passenger nginx module is not compiled. Chef's not_if method takes a string (or block) which it will execute and if exit code is 0 will skip the step otherwise if non zero code will perform the step.